# Solving the time-independent Schrödinger equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, quantum-mechanics

The time-independent Schrödinger equation is

$$\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi + V \psi = E \psi.$$

I am then told that the general solution for a uniform potential can be written as the sum of two counter-propagating plane waves,

$$\psi(r) = Ae^{ikz} + Be^{-ikz},$$

where

$$k^2 = \dfrac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E - V)$$

is found by substitution back into the time-independent Schrödinger equation.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to show me how the general solution $\psi(r) = Ae^{ikz} + Be^{-ikz}$ was found. Furthermore, I would greatly appreciate it if people would explain what is meant by the general solution for a "uniform potential", and how the two plane waves are "counter-propagating".

### My work:

$$\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla \psi(r) + V \psi(r) = E \psi(r)$$

$$\begin{align} &\therefore \dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \dfrac{d^2 \psi}{dr^2} + V \psi = E \\ &\Rightarrow \dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m} \dfrac{d^2 \psi}{dr^2} + (E - V) \psi = 0 \\ &\Rightarrow \dfrac{d^2 \psi}{dr^2} + \dfrac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E - V)\psi = 0 \end{align}$$

So we have the following characteristic equation:

$$\begin{align} &k^2 + \dfrac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E - V) = 0 \\ &\Rightarrow k^2 = \dfrac{2m}{\hbar^2}(V - E) \\ &\Rightarrow k = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{2m}{\hbar^2}(V - E)} \end{align}$$

If we let $A = \sqrt{\dfrac{2m}{\hbar^2}(V - E)}$, then we have that

$$\begin{align} \psi(r) = C_1 e^{A} + C_2 e^{-A}, \\ \psi'(r) = C_1A e^{A} - C_2 A e^{-A}, \\ \psi''(r) = C_1 A^2 e^{A} + C_2 A^2 e^{-A} \end{align}$$

But this is not the same as $\psi(r) = Ae^{ikz} + Be^{-ikz}$. And how do we account for the fact that we have a "uniform potential"?

Comment: "I am then told that the general solution for a uniform potential..." Who is telling you this? Why can't you ask them?

Comment: @Neal It is the appendix of a textbook. They left out all of the details; this is all there is.

Comment: A uniform potential is one that does not vary, i.e., $V$ is constant. So it can be subtracted from the energy to yield the eigenvalue equation $-\nabla^2 \psi = (2m/\hbar)(E-V)\psi$. You then use standard separation of variables to derive the general form of the solution.

Comment: I imagine the two waves are called "counterpropagating" because their exponents are identical but opposite in sign, so they can be thought of as two waves of the same frequency oscillating exactly out of cycle with each other.

Comment: Your argument is correct. Note that for $E>V$ (in the classically allowed region), your $A$ is imaginary.

Comment: @lcv Thanks for the clarification. Why is $E > V$ in the classically allowed region?

Comment: For $E<V$ the potential acts like a barrier (classically). The particle would be stuck.

Comment: @lcv Hmm, interesting. I guess that settles it. I put a small bounty on the question, just in case anyone wants to post a more comprehensive answer (for the sake of completeness). Thanks again for taking the time to clarify this for me.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this treatment work the same for a potential that is piecewise constant. Then you just have to glue the pieces together (by playing with the $C_i$s). In general the wavefunction will be exponentially decaying in classically forbidden regions (and will behave like a wave in the other regions).

Answer (score 1):

The Schrödinger equation describes the evolution of the wave function of a particle (or system). When you assume that the wave function $\Psi(x, t)$ is separable, *i.e.*, $\Psi (x,t) = \psi (x) T(t)$, you obtain the following Schrödinger equation,
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\Psi(x,\,t) + V(x)\Psi(x,t) = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x,\,t).$$
This equation is equivalent to these two equations:
\begin{align}
& i\hbar \frac{d T(t)}{dt} = E \, T(t) \\
& -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2 \psi (x)}{dx^2}+V(x) \psi (x) = E \, \psi (x),
\end{align}
where the second equation is known as the *time-independent* Schrödinger equation.

The solution to the first equation is given by
$$T(t) = e^{-i\frac{Et}{\hbar}}.$$
When you have a uniform potential, *i.e.* the function $V$ is constant, the second equation can also be solved easily using the method you described. The characteristic equation is given by:
$$k^2 + \dfrac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E - V) = 0.$$
There are two cases, either $E-V < 0$. In that case the solution is given by:
$$\Psi(x) = A \exp(-k x) + B \exp(kx), \quad k = \sqrt{\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(V-E)}.$$
Either $E-V > 0$. In that case the solution is given by:
$$\Psi(x) = A \exp(-ik x) + B \exp(ikx), \quad k = \sqrt{\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(V-E)}.$$
That is for the mathematical part.

Now physically you have some constraints on your wave function. The first one being that, as $|\Psi(x)|^2$ represents a probability distribution, as such it must sum to one. The wave function is also continuous and differentiable. In a typical problem, you are given a potential and all these conditions gives you constraints on the possible solutions.

The canonical example is an infinite potential well, *i.e.* a potential that is finite between $0$ and $L$, and infinite everywhere else. In that case, it is easy to see that $\Psi(x)$ must be zero where the potential is infinite and so that by continuity of the wave function the wave vector $k$ can only take discrete value. Hence the quantization of the energy. See this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box

You can also study cases where the potential is piecewise constant. This gives rise to funny quantum phenomena such as the tunnel effect. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You wrote that $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\Psi(x,\,t) + V(x)\Psi(x,t) = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x,\,t)$ is the time-independent Schrödinger equation, but I think you meant $\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi + V \psi = E \psi$ (as you wrote below it), since yours is still dependent on time.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mixed up.